# Heroku doesn't delete database when I remove it on server (Django app)

Tags: django, heroku

I logged in to my app's directory in Heroku's server:

```
Heroku run bash -app appname
```

Then I deleted my database:

```
Rm -r dev.db
```

However when I try to sync my database it doesn't create new tables. And when I go to the production site, it still has all database contents and lets me log in, etc.

Any insight into what I'm doing wrong? I want to completely recreate the database.

Note: I have a Django app

Update: Here are my database settings

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3", # Add "postgresql_psycopg2", "postgresql", "mysql", "sqlite3" or "oracle".
        "NAME": PROJECT_ROOT + os.sep + "dev.db",                       # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        "USER": "",                             # Not used with sqlite3.
        "PASSWORD": "",                         # Not used with sqlite3.
        "HOST": "",                             # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        "PORT": "",                             # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

then I have this injection code for Heroku:

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')}
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Could you post the database settings from your `settings.py`?

Comment: I'm using SQLite and when I push to heroku it converts to postgreSQL. I edited my question above to include the database settings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heroku gives you a Postgres database by default. To completely remove it run:

```
heroku addons:remove heroku-postgresql:dev
```

Then to create a new one:

```
heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:dev
```

If it does not automatically promote this to your main DB (you should a config var DATABASE_URL if so) then run:

```
heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COLORHERE
```

Comment: @CraigKerstiens, great answer, it seems the name of the plan has changed, so for me what worked was to use `hobby-dev` instead of `dev`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it through the UI in the Heroku add-ons tab. You just have to delete the add-on and the DATABASE_URL will be editable/removable.